# What is slowing down simple collection conversions

Tags: c#, arrays, collections, foreach, ienumerable

I have a simple while loop

```
IEnumerable<Foo> collection;
while (!bc.IsCompleted)
{
   collection = bc.Take();
}
```

bc is a `BlockingCollection<IEnumerable<Foo>>`. The bc contains 9 IEnumerable collections and a total of 2.6million Foo objects. The loop takes about 640ms to run on my machine. As soon as I add a foreach loop after Take() within the while loop the time it takes to run explodes to 2400ms.

```
foreach(Foo foo in collection)
{
}
```

Iterating over 2.6 million elements within a List or Foo[] or IEnumerable that I setup separately, took about 54ms.

The same happens if instead of the foreach loop I simply add a collection conversion such as

```
List<Foo> fooList = collection.ToList();
```

or

```
Foo[] fooArray = collection.ToArray();
```

It suddenly also takes north of 2000ms to execute.

How can this be? I am completely running out of explanations or possible reasons. Anyone who could point me to what I am missing here? The slow down cannot be caused by locking/blocking because I do not alter the way the BlockingCollection is accessed between my comparisons.

Thanks for any input.

Comment: It takes time to create an array or an indexer for 2.6 million elements

Comment: disagree, I created it in less than 100 milliseconds as I pointed out above. Not only did I create it I also iterated over it in sub 100 milliseconds. This can clearly not be it...

Comment: So `bc` is a `BlockingCollection<IEnumerable<Foo>>`?

Comment: correct, it is. Sorry I will add that info above...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As with others LINQ methiods out there (and im guessing you are using LINQ's take), this method works with a deffered execution:

> This method is implemented by using deferred execution. The immediate return value is an object that stores all the information that is required to perform the action. The query represented by this method is not executed until the object is enumerated either by calling its GetEnumerator method directly or by using foreach in Visual C# or For Each in Visual Basic

This means that if you dont add the ToList() call of the foreach loop, the sole call to Take doesnt really produce any results, and the actuall results are only brought when you are using the iterator (of foreach/tolist), hence the performance difference.

Your comparison to just iterating over list might not provide accurate results; Its not the iteration over the List(foo) that takes time, its probably the selection of the elements from the blocking collection you are using that slows everything down.

 [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460684.aspx) claims that using regular foreach on the BlockingCollection (which is probably what happens when u r using the LINQ supplied Take, which works on IEunmerable in this case) uses a snashop of the underlying collection, and this can surely slow done the processing on huge collections.

Comment: would this apply to the Take() method of a BlockingCollection? I do not see any indication in MSDN that this method is a Linq query or extension. Just wondering...

Comment: You are correct, theres also a Take on the blockingcollection as well(not the linq extension method). yet, the original point stands: it takes more time when you loop with foreach/call to list, because only THEN your ienumerable is evaluated. if u r convinced that simply iterating over the ienumerable works faster when u dont get it from the blockingcollection - i suggest u upload ur compared code as well to let us see the differences

Comment: I did not suggest you were incorrect just wanted to make sure its not related to Linq as I do not think I messed with Linq in that specific example. I will look to convert to List() within the producer and see whether the time increase is shifted back from Consumer to Producer. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: Converting ToList() before adding to the blocking collection shifted the time consumption back to the producer and away from the consumer as desired, exactly as you suggested. Thank you. I marked your answer as the correct one because you included the most context. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

What kind of `IEnumerable` are you putting into the queue?

Keep in mind that LINQ queries are using delayed execution; your code might end up evaluating the query on the consumer thread. Try calling `ToList()` on the producer thread before you put the element into the queue.

Comment: Ienumerable<Foo> where Foo is a very lightweight class object (3 members, one of type long, two of type double). But you are right in that I added items to IEnumerable within the producer. Let me make some adjusted and I report back. Thanks for the pointer...

Comment: That was exactly the problem. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

An `IEnumerable` can represent a deferred operation. Sometimes (say, with LINQ, or iterator blocks) the contents of the ienumerable is not actually generated until it is iterated over.

So, your `IEnumerable<Foo>` might contain enough information to generate the `Foo`s, but not actually do so until you iterate over the enumerable, either in a `foreach` or using `ToList`. That's why those operations take a long time.

Comment: would this apply to the Take() method of a BlockingCollection? I do not see any indication in MSDN that this method is a Linq query or extension. Just wondering...

Comment: This has nothing to do with `Take`, it's got to do with the actual items in the collection in the first place!

Comment: Thanks, I get your point now, I am making some adjustments in my code and will report back